# Nginx returns index.html page for RESTapi endpoint calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a RESTapi and Vue.js SPA.

I host both in one EC-2 instance.

[image]

> Note that I put /api/* location block first.

If I access Normal public DNS name something.compute.amazonaws.com this should load Vue.js Front end. Which is currently works.

If I access something.compute.amazonaws.com/api/user I expect a JSON response from the API. But this also returns the same index.html page.

[image]

Seems API requests doesn't redirect to the API correclty.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not an expert with nginx but I've never seen any `location` definition to have an "*" before.

Comment: Tried removing the `*` in the **location/api/** ?